# Java NIO2 Files.copy() vs. Bash cp - Performance comparison

Tags: java, bash, cp, file-copying, nio2

I have a Java program which is launched through command-line by a Bash script, which is in turn called at various intervals by cron.

There are several operations performed by this program, the first being the copy of a possibly large number of more or less large files. (Anything from 10000 files of 30 KB to 1 big 1 GB file, but both of these are edge cases.)

I am curious about how this step should be accomplished to ensure performance (as in speed).

I can use either Bash's `cp` function, or Java 7's `Files.copy()`. I will run my own tests but I'm wondering if someone has **any comparison data I could take into account before deciding on an implementation?**

Comment: Did you have any preformance issue with the java version?

Comment: Also consider to use SSD disks, if you don't use already.

Comment: I wouldn't write code if you don't have to. Use `cp.` It's had a lot of work over decades.